# LINQ query has me baffled

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-4

How would I write a LINQ query to do the following?

I have a database table with a schema like this:

```
ID - Int  
Time - DateTime  
RecordType - Int  
Msg - String
```

I want to get the newest (using 'Time' field) record for each 'RecordType'

Another restriction is that I'm only interested in certain RecordTypes - those contained in an int array.

The result of the query would be one record per RecordType - the newest record for this type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var results = source.GroupBy(x => x.RecordType)
                    .Where(g => myRecordTypes.Contains(g.Key))
                    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).First())
                    .ToList();
```

`myRecordTypes` is `int[]` with a set of `RecordType`s you'd like to get as a result.

`result` will be `List<Record>` with one item per `RecordType`.

You can change to it to be e.g. `Dictionary<int, Recort>` by `RecordType`:

```
var results = source.GroupBy(x => x.RecordType)
                    .Where(g => myRecordTypes.Contains(g.Key))
                    .Select(g => new { g.Key, item = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).First() })
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Group them by record types, filter out the ones you want, and then select out the first of the items in that group ordered by time.

```
int[] recordTypes = GetRecordTypes();
var query = context.Table.GroupBy(item => item.RecordType)
    .Where(group => recordTypes.Contains(group.Key))
    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(item => item.Time).FirstOrDefault());
```